# Web service client code compiler error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I have written the following three java files by following a book on javaEE with Glassfish.

ClassValidator.java

```
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public class CardValidator {
    public boolean validate(CreditCard creditCard){
        Character lastDigit = creditCard.getNumber().charAt(creditCard.getNumber().length()-1);
        if(Integer.parseInt(lastDigit.toString())%2 != 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

CreditCard.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class CreditCard {
    private String number;
    private String expiryDate;
    private Integer controlNumber;
    private String type;
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getExpiryDate() {
        return expiryDate;
    }
    public void setExpiryDate(String expiryDate) {
        this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
    }
    public Integer getControlNumber() {
        return controlNumber;
    }
    public void setControlNumber(Integer controlNumber) {
        this.controlNumber = controlNumber;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


}
```

Main.Java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
    creditCard.setNumber("12341234");
    creditCard.setExpiryDate("10/10");
    creditCard.setType("VISA");
    creditCard.setControlNumber(1234);

    CardValidator cardValidator = new CardValidatorService().getCardValidatorPort();
    cardValidator.validate(creditCard);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in Main.java at the line where the callValidatorService constructor is called(CardValidatorService cannot be resolved to a type). How to overcome this error? what other configurations should I make, to run this successfully?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Is there a class called CardValidatorService?

Comment: CardValidatorService cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: no. I thought there is something happening behind the scene